# How to fix barn wall gaps at foundation and wall joint

Tags: walls, foundation, siding, barn

[image]We just acquired a new property and the barn here is kinda strange. As shown in the photos, there is a base 2 by 4 which is running around the slab foundation instead of on top of it. Because of this, grass and other plants grow in the barn between the corrugated metal siding and wood. Plus, insects easily make their way inside and there is some wood damage from them. I also find water damage periodically in the boards as the water can wick up the wood.

[image]

My plan was to insulate and finish the barn, but I am not sure how to seal the bottom of the walls.

How would you suggest we set about remedying this?

Comment: That 2x4 is probably just a nailing/screwing strip for the sliding.

Comment: Assume these are inside pictures, what does the outside look like?

Comment: Yep, these are inside. Outside is pretty simple - the bottom of the 2x4 is open and the metal ends with a little finishing strip at the same height. Most of the 2x4 runner is above the ground by an inch or so, but some of it is below. Any ideas on some way of preventing grass from growing through the small gaps in the base and sealing it from outside moisture?

Comment: Not sure this is the "correct" solution, but have you considered filling the gaps with self-leveling concrete? You would need to make a temporary form or barrier to prevent the concrete from spilling over onto your main floor, but maybe that would work. And it would probably be cleaner than using expanding foam. This won't help with the water wicking up the wood, though.